# wiringPiISR: unable to open /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value: No such file or directory

Tags: java, gpio

I am getting this :wiringPiISR: unable to open /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value: No such file or directory

Running it with tomcat and tomcat is running as root
TOMCAT7_USER=root

run as service in /etc/init.d/

When it get above error it kills all tomcat and have to restart ( service tomcat7 restart)

How do I fix this?

```
// ***************************************
public synchronized void GetInput1(int trigerpin, int outputpin) throws     InterruptedException {
System.out.println("<--Pi4J--> GPIO interrupt test program");

// setup wiringPi
if (Gpio.wiringPiSetup() == -1) {
    System.out.println(" ==>> GPIO SETUP FAILED");
    return;
}

Gpio.pinMode(1, Gpio.INPUT);
Gpio.pinMode(2, Gpio.INPUT);

Gpio.pullUpDnControl(1, Gpio.PUD_UP);
Gpio.pullUpDnControl(2, Gpio.PUD_UP);

Gpio.wiringPiISR(1, Gpio.LOW, new GpioInterruptCallback() {
    @Override
    public void callback(int pin) {
        System.out.println(" ==>> GPIO PIN " + pin + " - INTERRUPT DETECTED");
    }
});
Gpio.wiringPiISR(2, Gpio.LOW, new GpioInterruptCallback() {
    @Override
    public void callback(int pin) {
        System.out.println(" ==>> GPIO PIN " + pin + " - INTERRUPT DETECTED");
    }
});
}


}
```

Example was from https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j/blob/master/pi4j-example/src/main/java/WiringPiGpioInterruptExample2.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above helped you until reboot this look to be working.

I run:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-ui-mods

and that looks to be helping.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

gpio export 18 in

echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value